# Hazelcast failes liveness probe in OpenShift when loading a large map

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, hazelcast

We have Hazelcast 4.2 on OpenShift deployed as a standalone cluster and stateful set. We use Mongo  as a backing data store (it shouldn't matter) and the docker image is created with a copy of dockerfile from Github Hazelcast project with all the package repositories replaced with our internal company servers.

We have a MapLoader which takes a long time (30 minutes) to load all the data. During this load time the cluster fails to respond to liveness and readiness probes:

`Readiness probe failed: Get http://xxxx:5701/hazelcast/health/node-state: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`

and so OpenShift kills the nodes that are loading the data.

Is there any way to fix it, so Hazelcast responds with "alive" and "not ready" instead of timing out the connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the time for POD to check the health of POD if you are loading data initially.

https://github.com/hazelcast/charts/blob/d3b8d118da400255effc81e67a13c1863fee5f41/stable/hazelcast/values.yaml#L120

Above is helm example line showing the readiness and liveness configuration.

You can change the `initialDelaySeconds` to wait and after that seconds only **Hazelcast**  will start checking the health.

Accordingly you can also adjust the other probes configuration like **failureThreshold**: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

if `initialDelaySeconds` is not helpful, still you can increase the configuration for the **readiness** & **liveness** accordingly and increase the timeout whenever map loader loading the data.

Also only in liveness your POD or container get restart if Readiness failing K8s will mark your POD as not ready to accept traffic. So while loading data you can increase the liveness configuration so it never failed and set to max possible.

> The kubelet uses liveness probes to know when to restart a container.
> For example, liveness probes could catch a deadlock, where an
> application is running, but unable to make progress. Restarting a
> container in such a state can help to make the application more
> available despite bugs.
>
> The kubelet uses readiness probes to know when a container is ready to
> start accepting traffic. A Pod is considered ready when all of its
> containers are ready. One use of this signal is to control which Pods
> are used as backends for Services. When a Pod is not ready, it is
> removed from Service load balancers.

You can also set the `restartPolicy` to `Never` so the container will not restart.

Comment: That's what we did as a workaround for now, but we would like to have functional readiness and liveness probes and increasing those timeouts will impede our ability to monitor the cluster during normal operation (after the map loads). We would rather have Hazelcast reply to readiness/liveness probes with alive but not ready instead of refusing the connection, rather than work around it.

Comment: You should first investigate why the MapLoader takes that long. This could happen for a variety of reasons including slowness of database, small network bandwidth or the actual implementation of MapLoader itself. Once you have made certain that nothing everything is solid and efficient as it could be, you can then look into tuning health-check probes.